# Uncaught NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

Tags: vscode-debugger, deno

In `test.ts` I have a simple file like this:

```js
const text = await Deno.readTextFile("a.md");
console.log(text);
```

It runs fine with `deno run --allow-read .\test.ts`. However using the debugger it throws error:

```
error: Uncaught NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2): readfile 'a.md'
const text = await Deno.readTextFile("a.md");
             ^
```

Why is that? Here is the content of `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "--allow-read"
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This almost certainly means that the program's working directory is not the one you think it is.

Comment: I open another question to discuss it in detailed: [Why doesn't `console.log(Deno.cwd())` print anything in the debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76891244/3416774)