# Why doesn't `console.log(Deno.cwd())` print anything in the debugger?

Tags: vscode-debugger, deno, working-directory

I have a simple `path/to/test.ts` script:

```js
console.log(Deno.cwd())
```

It runs fine with `deno run --allow-read .\test.ts` and returns `path/to` as expected. However using the debugger it returns nothing before exiting.

Why is that? Here is the content of `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "--allow-read"
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

I try `${fileDirname}`, `${workspaceFolder}` and `${cwd}` value for the `cwd` key but it doesn't help.

<sub>See more: [Visual Studio Code Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

[Also asked on GitHub](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20144)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger is a separate process with its own I/O streams (e.g. console).

When debugging a program, any data that's emitted to one of the program's I/O streams (e.g. `stdout` via `console.log`) will not be forwarded to the debugger's console until after the debugger connects to the program and creates a pipe to that stream. That connection process takes time, and almost certainly won't happen until after the single `console.log` statement already finishes in the example program that you showed.

Deno's `run` command supports an argument to delay execution until after a debugger connects (added in [denoland/deno#17001](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/17001)) — this argument is `--inspect-wait`.

[From the manual](https://deno.land/manual@v1.36.1/getting_started/command_line_interface#other-runtime-flags):

> ### Other runtime flags
>
> More flags which affect the execution environment.
>
> ```txt
> (snip)
>
> --inspect-wait=<HOST:PORT>   activate inspector on host:port and wait for ...
>
> (snip)
> ```

Include it in the array of args in `configurations.runtimeArgs` in `./.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "--inspect-wait", // include this argument for debugging
        "--allow-read"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After adding that argument, I can run your example reproduction files in a VS Code workspace using the debugger and I see this in the debugger console:

```txt
/Users/deno/.deno/bin/deno run --inspect-wait --allow-read ./test.ts
/Users/deno/so-76891244                                                test.ts:1
```

Here are the software versions I used to reproduce the issue:

```txt
so-76891244 % code --version
1.81.1
6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
arm64

so-76891244 % deno --version
deno 1.36.1 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 11.6.189.12
typescript 5.1.6
```

---

Edit: It looks like a Deno core team member just [responded at your GitHub issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20144#issuecomment-1677291365) with a summarized version of the same info.

Comment: why can't the debugger connect immediately?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891244/why-doesnt-console-logdeno-cwd-print-anything-in-the-debugger/76899578?noredirect=1#comment135569862_76899578) @Ooker It connects as fast as it can, but Deno is faster than that: that’s why you have to tell Deno to wait by using that arg.